# Linq to SQL ForeignKeyReferenceAlreadyHasValueException

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, linq-to-sql

I had a look at several threads but I am not seeing the solution to fit my purpose 
(at least I don't understand how I could go about implementing it)

I have a WCF Service that uses Linq to SQL in order to retrieve, update and delete objects on my SQL Server.

I have created a simple Relational database which has a 
1 to many relationship between Customer and Order, 
1 to many relationship between Order and OrderDetails,

now My Orders has a Foreign key for CustomerID, and OrderDetails has a Foreign kwy for Order ID.

however OrderDetails also contains a FK for ProductID in a Products Table.

Basically what I am trying to do right now is amend OrderDetails using the OrderID and adding another product using ProductID.

I am having problems with that though as I keep receiving the ForeignKeyReferenceAlreadyHasValueException

I have written this which I know is completely wrong but at the time I wasn't aware (I am completely new to SQL, Linq to SQL etc) that I cant do this.

```
            OrderDetail item = new OrderDetail();                
            item.OrderID = orderItem.OrderID;
            item.ProductID = orderItem.ProductID;
            item.ProductQuantity = orderItem.ProductQuantity;                              
            jacksDB.OrderDetails.InsertOnSubmit(item);
            jacksDB.SubmitChanges();
```

I read that I had to map out the entity or something along those lines using a common line of code such as this

```
            var order = jacksDB.Orders.Single(o => o.OrderID == orderItem.OrderID);
            var orderDetail = order.OrderDetails.Single(o => o.OrderID ==    orderItem.OrderID);
            orderDetail.ProductID = orderItem.ProductID;
            orderDetail.ProductQuantity = orderItem.ProductQuantity;
            orderDetail.Discount = orderItem.Discount;
            jacksDB.OrderDetails.InsertOnSubmit(orderDetail);
            jacksDB.SubmitChanges();
```

could someone perhaps show and if its not too much to ask explain a little as to how I can correctly go about inserting a New OrderDetail Record into my OrderDetails table using an existing OrderID (FK) so as to "Edit and add/remove a Product to an Existing Order"

Thanks in advance for your help

John

Comment: Perhaps you could post the SQL required to create your tables including the primary and foreign keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so you are getting this error,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.foreignkeyreferencealreadyhasvalueexception.aspx

ForeignKeyReferenceAlreadyHasValueException

And the link says this about it,

Represents errors that occur when an attempt is made to change a foreign key when the entity is already loaded.

I think what you need to do is load the Order that you are talking about, and it will have a list of OrderDetails associated with it. If you want to remove one of those references you need to remove the OrderDetail from the OrderDetails list.

I think you need to do something like this,

```
using (DataClasses1DataContext context = new DataClasses1DataContext())
{
    Customer customer = context.Customers.Where(x => x.CustomerID == 1).Single();
    Order order = new Order();
    // set some order fields here
    customer.Orders.Add(order);

    OrderDetail orderDetail = new OrderDetail();
    order.OrderDetails.Add(orderDetail);

    orderDetail.Product = context.Products.Where(x => x.ProductID == 2).Single();
    orderDetail.ProductID = orderDetail.Product.ProductID;

    context.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Try it without InsertOnSubmit, but still keep the SubmitChanges. I suggest that because you are already adding the record by setting this,

```
order.OrderDetails.Add(orderDetail);
```

So you probably don't need to insert it again.

Comment: Thanks peter, what I am trying to achieve is adding a new OrderDetails Record with an existing OrderID such OrderID = 7; when I created an order with lets say 5 products, I would like to add a 6th product to an order that has already been created

Comment: So have you tried looking at the Order record? Does it have an OrderDetails property, which is a list of items. Add the OrderDetails to that.

Comment: Does OrderDetail and Product have a one to one relationship? You will also need to set the OrderDetails.Product record to the Product. I am just going by feel here, haha.

Comment: OrderDetail and Product have a many to 1, as in Many OrderDetails to one Product, and I am scared by that haha so I need to start at customer, get orders where customerid= cid, then get order.orderdetails where orderid = oid and then how would I set the product? would I get orderdetail.product where productid - pid and then insertonsubmit?

Comment: thanks peter that would be great, i have never done something like this so it looks quite complex but I think I am starting to see where I need to be heading

Comment: It should be what I am suggesting now, I am not sure whether you have to set the ProductID as well as the Product, but you probably do.

Comment: No problem. Glad to be of assistance.